# Switch case statement doesn't loop

Tags: c, switch-statement, case, break

All its doing is running functions but for some reason it doesn't break after I press `r`, it just runs the function then ends the program.

```
int main()
{
    char key = 0;
    PPMImage *img = NULL;
    do {
        puts("\tPress r to read in an image in ppm format");
        puts("\tPress s to save image in ppm format");
        puts("\tPress q to quit");
        
        scanf(" %c", &key);
        clear_to_end(stdin);
        switch (key) {
            case 'r':
                load_file("fname");
                free(img->data);
                break;

            case 's':
                save_file(img);
                break;

            case 'q':
                puts("\tTerminating program...");
                break;

            default:
                puts("\tInvalid Input");
                break;
        }
    } while (key != 'q');
}
```

Comment: What in this code do you think *should* make the program "break after I press r"?

Comment: About `free(img->data);`. The variable `img` is `NULL` and nothing changes that (not even in `load_file` or `save_file`) and then you dereference it: ka-*sploot*.

Comment: Ah yes. That was a silly mistake I made.

Comment: ...and when you call `save_file(img);` that's unrelated to anything that happens in `load_file`. BTW try to avoid kludges like `clear_to_end(stdin);` which is unnecessary here, and rarely is if you understand how `scanf` handles whitespace (which you appareently do).

Comment: should it be free(img)?
also, are you defining somewhere before this code what PPMImage is, if not use unsigned char *img = NULL;

Comment: here is a good tool to test your code:
https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler

Answer (score 0):

The reason the program exits is it has undefined behavior:

- `load_file("fname");` may load the image file, but no side effect occurs on `img`
- `free(img->data);` dereferences null pointer `img`, causing a segmentation fault and program termination.

Assuming `load_file` returns a pointer to `PPMImage` and your intent is to free a previously read image, change the code to:

```
        case 'r':
            if (img) {
                // free the previous image
                // write a function to free what was allocated
                free_file(img);
            }
            img = load_file("fname");
            break;
```